# Failed to initialize repository when starting Oracle Spatial Studio

Tags: oracle, spatial, oracle-spatial

After I haven't used it for about a month, I want to start my Oracle Spatial Studio on my local machine (localhost).
The connection works and I get the notification:

> Found Spatial Studio repository. Initializing metadata...

It looks like Initializing is not working, notification in the app:

> Failed to initialize repository. Please verify the information and try again.

Console Error:

```
    SEVERE: Unable to initialize metadata schema !
Jun 01, 2023 4:26:36 PM oracle.sgtech.jee.Bootstrap createGlobalMetadataSchema
SEVERE: ******* Default metadata schema could not be loaded; status is INVALID . Check previous log entries for more information *******
```

The sgtech_config.json (folder: .sgtech) looks like that:

```
{
  "version" : "22.1.0",
  "_comments" : [
    "Product Configuration for Oracle Spatial Studio",
    "Top level properties are:",
    " - work_dir: the runtime working folder of the Studio app; empty to use same folder as this configuration file.",
    " - https_only:  if set to 'true', then Studio will only allow HTTPS access",
    " - master_seed: the randomly generated seed used by Studio for security purposes",
    " - metadata_schema: defines details of the Studio's own metadata schema in a 12.2+ Oracle database instance.",
    " - upload: defines settings related to dataset uploads",
    " - logging: application-wide logging settings",
    " - jobs: application-wide settings related to internal job queuing"
  ],
  "work_dir" : "",
  "https_only" : true,
  "master_seed" : "aZmwLaRTS6wLDG9LN7V43fqlykONdBhW",
  "metadata_schema" : {
    "_comments" : [
      "This section provides connection details to the Studio's own metadata schema.",
      "Note that the property 'connection_manager' tells Studio who manages the schema connections.",
      "Value for 'connection_manager' must be 'CONTAINER' or 'SPATIAL_STUDIO'."
    ],
    "connection_manager" : "SPATIAL_STUDIO",
    "studio_managed" : {
      "_comments" : [
        "To be used when 'connection_manager' is SPATIAL_STUDIO.",
        "Either 'database_url' or 'database_wallet' have to be specified, but not both.",
        "The 'database_url' property should look like 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/orcl'."
      ],
      "database_url" : "[URL TO DATABASE]",
      "database_user" : "user",
      "database_password" : "psw",
      "max_connections" : 64,
      "init_connections" : 30
    },
    "cache" : {
      "_comments" : [
        "Configures the in-memory cache of metadata objects.",
        "'enabled' specifies whether the cache is enabled or not.",
        "'max_size' specifies the maximum number of entries to be cached.",
        "'max_age_seconds' specifies how many seconds after the last write or update will ",
        "an entry be evicted. If value is <=0 then age-based eviction is disabled."
      ],
      "enabled" : true,
      "max_size" : 1500,
      "max_age_seconds" : 900
    }
  },
  "upload" : {
    "_comments" : [
      "Maximum combined size of dataset files allowed in an upload request.",
      "Default is 50 MB."
    ],
    "dataset_max_size" : 50
  },
  "logging" : {
    "_comments" : [
      "Configures the logging level for server loggers.",
      "Supported logging levels are: OFF SEVERE WARNING INFO CONFIG FINE FINER FINEST ALL",
      "'level' specifies the default logging level.",
      "Optional. The 'custom' key/value map overrides the default logging level on specific ",
      "          loggers; each key must be a valid logger name and its value must be the ",
      "          override logging level."
    ],
    "level" : "INFO"
  },
  "jobs" : {
    "_comments" : [
      "Configures jobs settings",
      "'init_threads_count' specifies the initial amount of threads available for the jobs to run."
    ],
    "init_threads_count" : 15
  }
}
```

Can anyone help on that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try scrolling up on the console to look for a clearer exception. Since this used to work, and you have not used it for a while, it may be that the password of the database account has expired. Or maybe the account was locked due to too many connection failures. Or even that your database is not up and running.

Try connecting to that account using sqlplus, or sqlcl or sql developer.